# how to remove numeric values like "_1 and _13" from a string?

Tags: r, string

I try to extract values like "astrocytes_mature" from "astrocytes_mature_1, astrocytes_mature_2...astrocytes_mature_13".

I tried as follow:

```
    test <- "astrocytes_mature_1"
    gsub("(_[0-9])", "", test)
    [1] "astrocytes_mature"
```

works fine but not for "astrocytes_mature_11"
I got  "astrocytes_mature1"

anyway to replace both in one code?

Comment: Try `gsub("(_[0-9]+)", "", test)`.

Comment: @Friede, great. it works. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Friede no need to capture if not used ie `gsub("_[0-9]+", "", test)` should work

Comment: Thanks, I know. Just kept what OP has written.